# How to create a daterange in two text boxes in Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two textboxes for start date and end date.I have used jquery date picker in both the text boxes .I want the first box to display this month and the other box to display next month.Also the date selected in the second box should always be after the first text box.I am new to Jquery.

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#startdate, #enddate").datepicker();
    $("#startdate, #enddate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
    $("#enddate").datepicker({
        maxDate: "+1M"
    });
});
</script>
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean if you select 8 of August in first and then in second datepicker you have to select date only after 8 of August, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem,

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5bC2/2/)

Code i used

```
  $("#from").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
         day=date.getDate()+1,
         month = date.getMonth() + 2,
         year = date.getFullYear();
      $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
    }
 });
```

have got the date and month  selected and using it assigned the starting date to the next datepicker.(have used different id for the datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
           $("#startdate").datepicker({
                minDate: 0, //adjust min date display on calender
                maxDate: "+60D", //adjust max possible date values
                onSelect: function(selected) {
                  $("#enddate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
                }
            });
            $("#enddate").datepicker({ 
                minDate: 0,
                maxDate:"+60D",
                defaultDate: '+1m',
                onSelect: function(selected) {
                   $("#startdate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
                }
            });
```